# When I execute a .run file as <user> it works fine. If I sudo run it, it cannot detect Java

Tags: rhel, sudo, environment-variables, java, jdk

I am trying to execute a .run file that will install some applications. I'm installing the application in /opt/... When I run it without sudo, the installer runs correctly but cannot write to /opt/. When I run it with sudo, the installer complains that it cannot find a valid Java installation on the machine.

Java was installed using the oracle rpm

```
$rpm -ivh --prefix=javapath jdk1.7.0_75.x86_64.rpm   

$ which java
/usr/bin/java
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/java-1.7.0/jdk1.7.0_75
$ sudo echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/java-1.7.0/jdk1.7.0_75
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/java-1.7.0/jdk1.7.0_75/bin
$ sudo echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/java-1.7.0/jdk1.7.0_75/bin
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_75"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_75
```

After this, a

```
$ ./installer.run
```

will work fine, but a

```
$ sudo ./installer.run
```

will return

```
Error: There has been an error.
The installer could not find a valid JAVA(tm) on this machine.
```

It's an application error not a system error.

Comment: Try `sudo -e` .

Comment: I tried sudo -e and it did not work (opened a text file to edit). However after some research I discovered -E would have worked.

Comment: That's what I meant. My bad. Hope it didn't cause any harm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `sudo visudo` or alternatively open `/etc/sudoers`

Check for the line `secure_paths="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"`,

If your Java is located somewhere else add that path to this list.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks. I have performed this installation in the path but never had to do this step (although this time I defined system environment variables in /etc/profile rather than just through export JAVA_HOME and export PATH. Do you know what might have caused this?

Comment: Looks like you just broke the security. You could add a new bin folder somewhere, add it to the secure_paths, and then add a link to the java vm in it. This way you are only making the java vm an exception.